# Why would I get a HttpError when requesting a token from IndentityServer 3

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I have a standard IndentityServer 3 application that I use to generate tokens for my applications. I deployed multiple instances of this application to different servers and I can successfully request tokens from all of them. Recently I deployed another instance to a Windows Server 2012 and started getting a HttpError when requesting tokens

[image]

I use the following code to request a token

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(identityServerUrl,clientId,clientSecret);

var result = tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("Test").Result;
```

Any ideas on what may be causing IdentityServer 3 to get a HttpError?

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/703 maybe this could help you out

Comment: What version of IIS

Comment: IIS 8.0.9200.16384

Comment: @KieranQuinn IIS 8.0.9200.16384

Comment: I haxve a feeling it's got to do with the certificate, I followed these step https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Certificates but I'm still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was occurring because of an IIS configuration. Double click on your server in IIS Manager and double click on Authentication

[image].

Make sure that obly Anonymous Authentication is enabled.

[image]

**Very Important:** Apply the same settings for your IdentityServer site.